# Run Php website native on Ipad

Tags: php, ipad, web, native

Hi Folks thank you for reading in advance ,

i made a web application running on html , css and php works fine .

The application is something that would be used when working in the field and regularly 3G or 4G isn't available so calling the application from the server isn't an option

Is there a way i could run my website folder "native" on my ipad .

i've seen phonegap but it seems thats only for html , css , and javascript .

Any other alternatives or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you could use Kodiak (http://www.becomekodiak.com/kodiak-php.html), I would still go with an HTML5 / javascript app because you get the advantage of being able to run both in the browser and on the iPad.

You could have a manifest file which would let the browser know what to cache, you have access to local storage, you have a possibility to update when a connection is available.

It is a bit more complex but in the end it is better because you can in theory synchronize the data both online and offline, it is the standard way of doing it and most browsers support it

Comment: This manifest works with php or only with javascript ? I'm more of a designer then a coder the only thing my application does is taking variables from a html form and images then parse it trough some php librarys and push out a word docx files with content and images . :)

Comment: well, if you are a designer, the stronger the reason to go that route... move a lot of the logic to html/javascript. So basically you could use a clientside template lib like angular generate your pages on the fly, have php generate your data as json and cache all these files/images and be cached (either on the local storage, some even have sql). Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: Thank you i'll take a look at that and figure to implement it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a jailbroken iPad, you could use something like http://ios-webstack.tk/install

If it's not jailbroken, then I'm pretty sure it's not possible

Comment: Thank you , i will probably check out the ios-webstack . Maybe a quick follow up . for android this is way easier right ? :)

Comment: Yup, you can install every app you want, even if they're not from the google play store.